# The bluetooth and wifi of my phone are unable to turn on.(Lumia 520)

Tags: lumia

When I connected my phone on the laptop, I think I clicked something in the wireless connection but I cannot remember what exactly I did.

Then when disconnected, the bluetooth and wifi cannot turn on no matter what I do. I already reset my phone. But nothing changed. What should I do?